# Volley images disappear

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-volley

I'm using volley to load images in my cursor adapter. The images successfully load, however, when I scroll away, and scroll back up [the image disappears](https://vid.me/48vf)

Here is the relevant code:

In the array initializer:

```
mImageLoader = MyApplication.getInstance().getImageLoader();
```

And in my bindView method:

```
storyImage.setImageUrl(imageURL, mImageLoader);
```

The mImageLoader initialization references to MyApplication.class, which can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/buneme/10ffb5ede0b4ad8b47db)

Comment: hi, did you find any fix for this volley image view problem?